# Retrieving Blob from MySQL database in Hibernate / JSF application

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I am having some trouble properly retrieving blob data from my database using java in my JSF 2.0 application. The first problem I am having is on my getter method for the Blob named "file" I get an error saying that "Basic attributes can only be of the following types..." basically saying that I can not return a Blob object. My code looks like what is below. Even with the error my code compiles. I have created a test method (the last bit of code below) and tried to test but it gives me runtime errors.

**Controller Bean**

```
import java.sql.Blob;

@Entity
@Table(named = "files")
@NamedQueries( {
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyBlob.getBlob",
    query = from MyBlob WHERE fileId =: fileId")
})
public class MyBlob implements Serializable {

     private Integer fileId;
     private Blob file;
     ...

     public Integer getFileId() {
         return fileId;
     }

     public void setFileId() {
         this.fileId = fileId;
     }

     public Blob getFile() {
         return file;
     }

     public void setFile(Blob file) {
         this.file = file;
     }

     ....

}
```

**BlobDao.java File method to get blob**

```
public MyBlob getBlob(Integer fileId) throws HibernateException {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try { 
      MyBlob blob = (MyBlob)session.getNamedQuery("MyBlob.getBlob").setInteger("fileId", fileId).uniqueResult();
      return blob;
    } catch(HibernateException e) {
         throw new HibernateException(e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**TestDao.java**

```
@Test
public void testBlob() {

    MyBlob test = blobdao.getBlob(1);  // 1 is a fileId that exists in the DB with a blob image file.
    Blob blob = test.getFile();
    try {
        System.out.println(blob.length));   //this prints a number but I dont think the right one. 
        if(blob.length > 0 ) {
             System.out.println(blob.toString() ); //errors out here
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
          return System.out.println("Failed");
    }
}
```

I am not sure that I am doing this right at all. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem: `catch(HibernateException e) { throw new HibernateException(e); }` that part is entirely superfluous. Remove it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on my getter method for the Blob named "file" I get an error saying that "Basic attributes can only be of the following types..." basically saying that I can not return a Blob object.

Indeed, a `java.sql.Blob` is not a persistent field or property that can be mapped by Hibernate/JPA. The JPA specification puts is like this:

> #### 2.1.1 Persistent Fields and Properties
>
> ...
>
> The persistent fields or properties of
>   an entity may be of the following
>   types: Java primitive types;
>   `java.lang.String`; other Java
>   serializable types (including wrappers
>   of the primitive types,
>   `java.math.BigInteger`,
>   `java.math.BigDecimal`, `java.util.Date`,
>   `java.util.Calendar`, `java.sql.Date`,
>   `java.sql.Time`, `java.sql.Timestamp`,
>   user-defined serializable types,
>   `byte[]`, `Byte[]`, `char[]`, and
>   `Character[]`); enums; entity types
>   and/or collections of entity types;
>   and embeddable classes (see section
>   2.1.5).

You should probably use the `Lob` annotation and change your attribute type. From the specification:

> #### 9.1.19 Lob Annotation
>
> A Lob annotation specifies that a
>   persistent property or field should be
>   persisted as a large object to a
>   database-supported large object type.
>   Portable applications should use the
>   Lob annotation when mapping to a
>   database Lob type. The `Lob`
>   annotation may be used in conjunction
>   with the `Basic` annotation. A `Lob`
>   may be either a binary or character
>   type. The `Lob` type is inferred from
>   the type of the persistent field or
>   property, and except for string and
>   character-based types defaults to
>   Blob.
>
> ...
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> @Lob @Basic(fetch=EAGER)
> @Column(name="REPORT")
> protected String report;
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> @Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)
> @Column(name="EMP_PIC", columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
> protected byte[] pic;
> ```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 2.1.1 "Persistent Fields and Properties"
  - Section 9.1.19 "Lob Annotation"

---

> Well my exact requirements are to retrieve the Blob from the database either as a Blob or a byte[], whatever works, and then somehow convert that into a valid InputStream object.

What about [`ByteArrayInputStream(byte[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream%28byte%5b%5d%29)?

Comment: So if I did this how would I retrieve the data? I need to get the data as a Blob object so I can call the getInputStream method on it. if I change it to a byte[] I can not call this method anymore.

Comment: @NewTOJSF `So if I did this how would I retrieve the data?` By using the getter? `I need to get the data as a Blob object so I can call the getInputStream method on it.` And why do you need this? Where did you mention that in your question? What are your **exact** requirements?

Comment: Well my exact requiredments are to retrieve the Blob from the database either as a Blob or a byte[], whatever works, and then somehow convert that into a valid InputStream object. I am using primefaces so I am trying to use their Dyna Image feature which will serve the images for me. In order to get the InputStream object I am under the assumption I need to call the getBinaryStream() method on the blob object. I have searched how to convert a byte[] array to an InputStream but I have not found anything that looks promising. Again I am very new to this so I am sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @NewTOJSF: No problem, it's just that readers can't guess what you're trying to achieve if you don't tell them :) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the `Blob` object is your Entity.
It might help if you print that as well.

Make sure your `Blob` returns `byte[]`

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob             
@Column(length = 104857600, nullable = false)
private byte[] data;
```

Comment: I don't understand when you say make sure your Blob returns byte[]. Can you possibly elaborate on that? Thanks.